# Xor encryption fails

Tags: c, encryption, xor

**Answer:**

I had to make a separate function for decryption that used *"rb"* to open the encrypted file and then use *"wb"* in the encryption function to write the encrypted data to the file.

---

I got a problem with my Xor encryption. The encryption works fine when encrypting the data in the file, but when it fails when I try to decrypt it. The problem is that the `fgetc` function only reads the first line and the second line and fails to decrypt 50% of the second line.

**Example:**

***Normal:***

```
This is a text, This is a text

This is a text, This is a text
```

***Encrypted***:

```
a¦_ÖÞ`×ûù‡ûÛ(‹Pñ»FŒ§U®7!¼ªãŸ<çÏ±\Î8ðs6Öã`GÒFAªÓV/Ç1t
```

***Decrypted***:

```
This is a text, This is a text

This is a text, ±Åãl«åé»–o„ F
```

I checked the code with a breakpoint and saw that the problem was that `fgetc` stopped reading the file after the second line but I don't know why. Maybe there is something wrong with my algorithm.

**Code:**

```
int encrypt_file(const char *filename, const char *key)
{
    int i               = 0;
    size_t key_len      = strlen(key);
    size_t key_count    = 0;
    size_t num_bytes    = 0;

    int *data = NULL;
    int byte = 0;

    FILE *file;

    fopen_s(&file, filename, "r");

    if ( file != NULL )
    {
        // get file size / number of bytes
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
        num_bytes = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

        // allocate enough memory for the data
        data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) *num_bytes);

        // stores the data from the file in the array
        while ( (data[i++] = fgetc(file)) != EOF );

        // encrypt the data
        for ( i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++ ) {
            data[i] = data[i]^key[key_count++];

            if ( key_count == key_len ) {
                key_count = 0;
            }
        }

        fclose(file);
        fopen_s(&file, filename, "w");

        // write the data from the array to the same file
        for ( i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++ ) {
            fputc(data[i], file);
        }

        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `"wb"` instead of `"w"` while opening the output file since it is not text anymore.

Comment: @timra is right about using "wb".  Also, insure your decrypt file is opened using "rb".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the encrypted data is no longer text anymore, you should use `"wb"` and `"rb"` while opening encrypted file for I/O.

Comment: Just for personal reference, what is it that caused this glitch specifically? Did an ASCII character's representation get changed to the EOL or EOF character?

Comment: Yeah, any value could exist in encrypted data, including `EOF` which confuses `fgetc()` if the file is opened in text mode.